# Hangout on Fedora25 and Black Screen during screenshare

Tags: fedora

I can screenshare both of my monitors, google chrome windows

When I screenshare my console or other apps (like Visual Paradigm IDE) - others just see a **black** screen

```
➜  /tmp loginctl                       
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
         3       1000 dmitry           seat0           
        c2         42 gdm              seat0           

2 sessions listed.
➜  /tmp loginctl show-session 3 -p Type
Type=x11
➜  /tmp loginctl show-session c2 -p Type
Type=x11
➜  /tmp gdm --version              
GDM 3.22.3
➜  /tmp cat /etc/gdm/custom.conf G wayland
5:# WaylandEnable=false
➜  /tmp
```

## How to resolve?

Comment: It seems a lot of people affected https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369218, but what's strange is that for some it works, for some - doesn't